# Performing validation on Login using nodejs and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, validation

I'm Having a User login using the below code:

```
OnSubmit(e) {
    const user = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login', user)
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(res.data.users))
        this.setState({ userData: res.data.users||{}, loggedin:true });
        console.log(this.state.userData);
      })
      localStorage.setItem("token", "got")
```

}
I want to perform a Validation That If user data does not match then show an alert error else it should Redirect to Dashboard like following code:

```
    if (this.state.loggedin) {
          return <Redirect to={`/UI/Navbar/Dashboard/${this.state.userData._id}`} />
        }

Here is the Backend in the Nodejs

router.route('/login').post((req,res)=>{
    
    users.findOne({
         email:req.body.email,
         password:req.body.password
    })
    .then(users=>{
        if(users){
            
            res.json({  users })
        }else{
           res.json('not found')
        }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.send('error:'+err)
    })
    
})
```

Comment: Can you mention, what is the error coming?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use an async function in this way:

```
router.route('/login').post(async (req,res)=>{
    
    // Get the user async
    const user = await users.findOne({
         email:req.body.email,
         password:req.body.password
         })

    if(user === null) res.status(404).json('not found').end() // Check if user exists

    res.json({user}) // return user
    
})
```

First you search the user asynchronously, then you check if the user exits, if it doesn't you return the 'not found', else you return the user. I also added an status code of not found, of course is not necesary